# How can I access both AWS Elasticache(Redis) and AWS EC2 (MongoDB) from same lambda function?

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, serverless-framework

I can access separately but I cannot connect both of theese services.(AWS Elasticache(Redis) and AWS EC2 (MongoDB)). I tried theese: EC2, Elasticache and Lambda in same security group in AWS VPC. Also tried EC2 and Elasticache in different security group AWS VPC and lambda has these security groups. But didn't change anything. I used serverless framework 1.0. These connections in localhost redis and EC2(MongoDB) worked together succesfully. When I was writing to console serverless deploy, these operations did'nt work. Postman error is: 502 Bad Gateway.

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Here it is(I can connect to redis succesfully):

```
var client = redis.createClient(config.cache.connection.port, config.cache.connection.endpoint);
                client.on("error", function (err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error: Redis connection was failed");
                    }else{
                        console.log("Success: Redis connection was established");
                    }
                });   
                client.set("FEED10", "feed", redis.print);
                client.get("FEED10", function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error: ", err);
                    }
                    console.log("DATA: ", data);
                    client.quit();
                });
```

Here it is(ı can connect to mongodb succesfully)

```
        var options = {
            user: config.database.connection.user,
            pass: config.database.connection.password,
            promiseLibrary: require('bluebird')
        }
        mongoose.connect(config.database.connection.endpoint, options, function(error) {
        // Check error in initial connection. There is no 2nd param to the callback.
            if(error){
                console.log("Error: MongoDB connection was failed");
            }
            else{
                console.log("Success: MongoDB connection was established");
            }
        });
```

Here it is(i can connect MongoDB but con not redis). Any ideas?

```
var options = {
            user: config.database.connection.user,
            pass: config.database.connection.password,
            promiseLibrary: require('bluebird')
        }
        mongoose.connect(config.database.connection.endpoint, options, function(error) {
        // Check error in initial connection. There is no 2nd param to the callback.
            if(error){
                console.log("Error: MongoDB connection was failed");
            }
            else{
                console.log("Success: MongoDB connection was established");
            }
        });

var client = redis.createClient(config.cache.connection.port, config.cache.connection.endpoint);
                client.on("error", function (err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error: Redis connection was failed");
                    }else{
                        console.log("Success: Redis connection was established");
                    }
                });   
                client.set("FEED10", "feed", redis.print);
                client.get("FEED10", function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error: ", err);
                    }
                    console.log("DATA: ", data);
                    client.quit();
                });
```

Comment: Does the lambda have permission to access the ec2 ? Usually by security groups

Comment: Your description of your security group settings sound like you don't understand how security groups work. Each service should use a separate security group, and the inbound rules of the MongoDB and Redis security groups should open the appropriate ports for those services, with the "source" for those inbound rules being the security group assigned to the Lambda function.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for your answer. I was opened to all traffic security group of MongoDB and Redis inbound rules and assigned this security group to lambda. source : 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0. I will try security groups seperately and assign to security of lambda. right?

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov thanks for your comment. ı was setted permissions( I guess you mean security groups ) as above comment.

Comment: @MarkB Hi again. seperate security groups in same VPC didn't work.

Comment: Did you check security groups, attached to elasticache instances allowing inbound access from ec2 and also outbound access from the security group attached to ec2 instance?

Comment: @Ashan thanks for your answer. Inbound and outbound access rules of security groups was open(All traffic). So ı think, any services of AWS can access to each other. What is wrong here? Should i set custom rules for security groups? and why ?